# Does chrome tab's Execute Script method involve a content Script as background has no access to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

While learning how to develop Chrome extensions, I have read that the *background.js* has no access to the tab page's DOM. So, I think this shouldn't work without Content Scripts. But, it still Works ... Why?

This is the *manifest.json* file

*manifest.json*

```
{ 
      "name": "Page Redder",
      "version": "2.0",
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab"``
      ],
      "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
      },
      "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Make this page red"
      },
      "manifest_version": 2
}
```

This is the *background.js*:

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works because it *is* using a content script. The API call to [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) is injecting the text string in the `code` property as a content script into the active tab of the current window, which is the tab being shown when the `browserAction` button is clicked. Thus,

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"
```

is executed as a content script.